# Java Sockets: Enable SSL debug for *just* a single socket?

Tags: java, ssl

SSL debug logs are noisy and verbose; is there a way of enabling SSL debug for just a single Socket in Java ?

(Rather than the usual way of enabling JVM-wide debugging using "-Djavax.net.debug=all" etc).

Comment: I don't think so (sadly), but for some applications it might be productive to use a logging proxy to do a similar job, e.g.: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/11/14/debugging-ssl-in-java-using-mitmproxy/.